# Test all links in a website

Tags: java, url

This program tests all links (URLs) in all pages of a website.

Testing a link (URL) means that the link (URL) is downloaded. If the download is
successful then a success message is printed for that link (URL) starting with "Success: ".
If the download fails (server returns error, etc.) then a failure message is printed
for that link starting with "Failed:".

External links (URLs) in the website are not tested. They are not printed but you
can uncomment the printing code and external links (URLs) will be printed.

Only link (URLs) starting with https:// are tested for success or failure. Pages
starting with http:// always result in failure.

The code is below:

---

### Test_All_Links_In_A_Website.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test_All_Links_In_A_Website {

    String https = "https://";
    String http = "http://";
    String protocol = null;
    String domain = null;
    HashSet<String> processedLinks = new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> pendingLinks = new HashSet<String>();

    boolean isExternalLink(String link) {

        String linkProtocol = getProtocol(link);
        if (linkProtocol.isBlank() == true) {
            return false;
        }

        String linkDomain = getDomain(link, linkProtocol);
        if (linkDomain.isBlank() == true) {
            System.out.println("BIG_ERROR: Domain should not be blank. Some error happened.");
            System.out.println("BIG_ERROR: Domain should not be blank. Some error happened.");
            System.out.println("BIG_ERROR: Domain should not be blank. Some error happened.");
            return true;
        }

        // if domains match then it is an internal link
        if (domain.compareToIgnoreCase(linkDomain) == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    } // end of isExternalLink

    String getAbsoluteURLWithDomain(String link) {

        String linkProtocol = getProtocol(link);

        if (linkProtocol.isBlank() == false) {
            return link;
        }

        return this.protocol + this.domain + "/" + link;

    } // end of getAbsoluteURLWithDomain

    void startProcessing() {

        URL url = null;
        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        String searchPattern = "(<a .*?)href\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)(<.*?/a.*?>)";
        String linkToProcess = null;
        String linkURL = null;
        String line = "";

        Iterator<String> itr = pendingLinks.iterator();

        System.out.println();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {

            //System.out.println();

            // get a link and remove it from pending links and add it to processedLinks
            linkToProcess = itr.next();
            pendingLinks.remove(linkToProcess);
            processedLinks.add(linkToProcess);

            //System.out.println("\ndebug: Processing link: \"" + linkToProcess + "\"...");
            try {
                url = new URL(linkToProcess);
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // let's establish a connection
                conn.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Failed: " + linkToProcess + ". Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println();
                // initialize iterator again because we have removed a link from pendingLinks
                itr = pendingLinks.iterator();
                continue;
            }

            try {

                //System.out.println("\ndebug: Response code: " + conn.getResponseCode() + ", for link: " + linkToProcess);

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    //System.out.println(line);
                    pat = Pattern.compile(searchPattern);
                    mat = pat.matcher(line);

                    while (mat.find() == true) {

                        linkURL = mat.group(2);
                        if (linkURL.isBlank() == true) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        linkURL = linkURL.trim();

                        if (isExternalLink(linkURL) == true) {
                            //System.out.println("External: " + linkURL);
                            continue;
                        }

                        linkURL = getAbsoluteURLWithDomain(linkURL);

                        // add link to pendingLinks if it is not in both HashSets
                        if ((processedLinks.contains(linkURL) == false) && (pendingLinks.contains(linkURL) == false)) {
                            pendingLinks.add(linkURL);
                        }

                    } // end of while mat.find

                } // end of while readLine

                br.close();

                System.out.println("Success: " + linkToProcess);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Failed: " + linkToProcess + ". Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println();
            } // end of try-catch block

            // initialize iterator again because we may have added more links to pendingLinks
            itr = pendingLinks.iterator();

        } // end of while itr.hasNext

    } // end of startProcessing

    String getProtocol(String url) {

        String emptyString = "";

        if ((url == null) || (url.isBlank() == true)) {
            return emptyString;
        }

        if (url.regionMatches(true, 0, https, 0, https.length()) == true) {
            return https;
        } else if (url.regionMatches(true, 0, http, 0, http.length()) == true) {
            return http;
        } else {
            return emptyString;
        }

    } // end of getProtocol

    String getDomain(String url, String protocol) {

        String emptyString = "";
        String searchPattern = null;

        if ((protocol == null) || (protocol.isBlank() == true)) {
            return emptyString;
        }

        if (url.indexOf('/', protocol.length()) == -1) {
            searchPattern = protocol + "(.*)";
        } else {
            searchPattern = protocol + "(.*?)/.*";
        }

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(searchPattern);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(url);

        if (mat.find() == false) {
            System.out.println("\ndebug: Error: Pattern did not match. Pattern: " + searchPattern + ", URL: " + url + ":    Exiting..");
            System.out.println("\ndebug: Error: Pattern did not match. Pattern: " + searchPattern + ", URL: " + url + ":    Exiting..");
            System.out.println("\ndebug: Error: Pattern did not match. Pattern: " + searchPattern + ", URL: " + url + ":    Exiting..");
            System.out.println("\ndebug: Error: Pattern did not match. Pattern: " + searchPattern + ", URL: " + url + ":    Exiting..");
            System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");
            return null;
        }

        return mat.group(1);

    } // end of getDomain

    void begin() {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String inputURL = "";

        try {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter a website URL for testing all links of the website (It should start with https://): ");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputURL = br.readLine();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");
            return;
        }

        //System.out.print("Input URL is: " + inputURL + "\n\n");
        inputURL = inputURL.trim();

        protocol = getProtocol(inputURL);

        if (protocol.compareTo(https) != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nError: The website URL does not start with " + https);
            System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");
            return;
        }

        domain = getDomain(inputURL, protocol);

        System.out.println("\ndebug: protocol: " + protocol + ", domain: " + domain);

        pendingLinks.add(inputURL);
        // start URL processing
        startProcessing();
        System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");

    } // end of begin

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test_All_Links_In_A_Website taloaw = new Test_All_Links_In_A_Website();

        taloaw.begin();

    } // end of main

} // end of Test_All_Links_In_A_Website
```

---

### some_part_of_output.txt

```
Enter a website URL for testing all links of the website (It should start with https://): https://www.wix.com

debug: protocol: https://, domain: www.wix.com

Success: https://www.wix.com
Success: https://www.wix.com/manage/analytics
Success: https://www.wix.com/ecommerce/website
Success: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/
Success: https://www.wix.com//velo/reference/wix-location
Success: https://www.wix.com/blog/ecommerce/category/best-sellers
Success: https://www.wix.com/my-account/site-selector/?title=analytics&buttonText=get%20started&actionUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fdashboard%2F%7B%7BmetaSiteId%7D%7D%2Fanalytics%2Freports%2F0b0118c7-98d3-4ec8-8b42-9d45bc145138%3FreferralInfo%3Danalytics_marketing_page
Success: https://www.wix.com/free/web-hosting
Success: https://www.wix.com/ecommerce/facebook-ads
Success: https://www.wix.com/blog/ecommerce/2021/10/house-of-suppliez
Success: https://www.wix.com/scheduling-software
Success: https://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/business/consulting-coaching
Success: https://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/restaurants-food/bar-club
Success: https://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/business/automotive-cars
Success: https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/2423
Success: https://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/landing-pages/promotional-page
Success: https://www.wix.com/website/templates/html/landing-pages/promotional-page/2
```

Comment: Please read and process the answer to your previous request before posting a new one. The same issues apply to this one.

Comment: I fixed wild card imports.

Answer (score 4):

In idiomatic Java, class names do not use Snake_Upper_Case. Use CamelCase.

`https` and `http` should be `private static final` constants with UPPERCASE names. They are never reassigned and are not intended for use outside of this class.

`http` is not used and should be deleted.

`processedLinks` and `pendingLinks` should be `private final`. They are never reassigned and are not intended for use outside of this class.

`protocol` and `domain` should be `private`. They are not intended for use outside this class.

In general, minimize the scope of all variables as much as possible. Code complexity is the enemy of sustainability, and variables that are not tightly scoped add complexity.

Using `final` indicates to readers that a value is not being reassigned. This makes it easier for them to understand the code.

When using collections such as `processedLinks` and `pendingLinks`, let the assigned type be the most general that is useful. The fact that the maps are `HashMap` is an implementation detail. The code only cares about the map contract.

As of Java 7, it is not necessary to specify the generic type on the right-hand side of an assignment.

It is not necessary to assign `protocol` and `domain` to be null. That happens implicitly at construction time.

I would expect to see `main` as the first method at the head of the file. Really, for non-toy applications, `main` would be in a separate class.

The code appears to read from bottom-to-top instead of top-to-bottom. That's much harder to read. `begin` should be the first method after main, not immediately before it.

Avoid needless abbreviations. `taloaw` is meaningless.

Comments indicating what block is being closed are noise and should be removed. If the code is so complex that the reader can't easily tell what's being closed, fix the complexity problem.

All the methods in the file are default scope, which means they're visible to every other class in the same package. They should all be `private`.

It's not safe to close objects inside a `try` block. They need to be closed in a `finally` block. Otherwise if an error occurs before `close` is reached, it will not be called. Even better is a `try-with-resources` block.

Minimize the code inside `try` blocks.

Using a `Scanner` would be better than building a `Reader`.

Catch the most-specific exception type that is appropriate. This is important so the block doesn't accidentally catch other types of exception instead of realizing they need to be handled differently. In particular, don't catch `Exception`, because that also catches all the RuntimeException instances, which is not correct behavior. RuntimeExceptions should be allowed to bubble up in almost all cases.

Don't leave commented-out code in the codebase.

Errors should be written to `System.err`, not `System.out`.

`getProtocol` and `getDomain` duplicate functionality on the `URL` library class. Prefer library classes and methods where possible. They have been heavily tested and are reliable.

It is generally preferred to only use uppercase for the first letter of an acronym to enhance readability. `inputURL` should be `inputUrl`.

It's unclear why the code is using `compareTo` instead of `equals` to see if two String values are identical, but when specifically checking for equality `equals` is strictly superior.

Don't use `System.out.println` to debug. This is what loggers are for.

The proper term for what the code is calling a "domain" is `host`.

Many of the comments are noise. `// start URL processing` the line before calling a method named `startProcessing` is of no value. Rename the method `startUrlProcessing` and lose the comment.

Do not tombstone variables at the head of a method. Minimize their scope. This makes the code significantly more readable.

Reassigning `itr` is a horrible hack. `Set` is the wrong data structure to use. A queue supports adding to the end and removing from the front. `pendingLinks` should be a `Queue<URL>`. Then instead of reassigning iterator, the code can loop over calls to `poll`

Once `pendingLinks` is turned into a `Queue<URL>`, it makes sense to make `processedLinks` a `Set<URL>`.

Don't swallow stack trace. In non-toy applications, it's critical for debugging.

Compiling a `Pattern` on every loop iteration completely misses the point of `Pattern`. The intent is to compile it once and reuse it, because compiling it is expensive.

Don't check if a method which returns boolean == true. It reads much cleaner as `while (matcher.find()) {`

Again, when using the matcher, leverage the URL class rather than doing string processing on a URL.

Using a named capture group might help readers understand what part of the string the code actually cares about.

If the string is converted to a URL right away, `isExternalLink` is extraneous. Just compare the hosts.

So now it turns out that the code don't need protocol to be a class-level variable, since it's only really needed in `begin`. It can be localized.

The code also doesn't need to track `domain`. The first URL added to `pendingLinks` has the desired host, and all later URLs compare their host to the page they're on, not the `domain` variable.

`processedLinks` and `pendingLinks` are both really only used in `startUrlProcessing`, so they can be localized to there. Pass in the first link as a method parameter to `startUrlProcessing`.

It's unclear why the method is named `startUrlProcessing`. It doesn't just start. It processes them all. `processUrls` would be better.

There are non-trivial further improvements that could be made, but I've spent enough time on this for now.

If you made all these changes, your code might look more like:

```
public class TestAllWebsiteLinks {

    private static final String HTTPS = "https://";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestAllWebsiteLinks testAllWebsiteLinks = new TestAllWebsiteLinks();
        testAllWebsiteLinks.begin();
    }

    private void begin() {
        final URL inputUrl;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter a website URL for testing all links of the website (It should start with https://): ");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            inputUrl = new URL(scanner.nextLine());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("\nError: The website URL is malformed: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");
            return;
        }

        if (!HTTPS.equals(inputUrl.getProtocol())) {
            System.err.println("\nError: The website URL does not start with " + HTTPS);
            System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");
            return;
        }
        processUrls(inputUrl);
        System.out.println("\n**** End of program ****");

    }

    private void processUrls(final URL inputUrl) {
        final Set<URL> processedLinks = new HashSet<>();
        final Queue<URL> pendingLinks = new LinkedList<>();
        pendingLinks.add(inputUrl);

        final Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile("(<a .*?)href\\s*=\\s*\"(?<url>.*?)\".*?>(.*?)(<.*?/a.*?>)");
        System.out.println();

        while (!pendingLinks.isEmpty()) {
            URL linkToProcess = pendingLinks.remove();
            processedLinks.add(linkToProcess);

            final HttpsURLConnection connection;
            try {
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) linkToProcess.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println();
                System.err.println("Failed: " + linkToProcess + ". Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println();
                continue;
            }

            try (Scanner pageScanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream())) {
                while (pageScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    Matcher matcher = searchPattern.matcher(pageScanner.nextLine());

                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        final URL url;
                        try {
                          url = new URL(matcher.group("url"));
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            System.err.println("Unable to parse URL " + matcher.group("url") + " on page " + linkToProcess);
                            System.err.println("Cause: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (linkToProcess.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(url.getHost())) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (!processedLinks.contains(url) && !pendingLinks.contains(url)) {
                            pendingLinks.add(url);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Success: " + linkToProcess);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println();
                System.err.println("Failed: " + linkToProcess + ".");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```